# Why I can't read openssl generated RSA pub key with PEM_read_RSAPublicKey?

Tags: c, encryption, openssl, rsa

I'm trying to read a RSA public key generated with openssl like this:

```
Private Key:
    openssl genrsa -out mykey.pem 1024

Public Key afterwards:
    openssl rsa -in mykey.pem -pubout > somewhere.pub
```

Then I try to read:

```
FILE *keyfile = fopen("somewhere.pub", "r");
RSA *rsa_pub = PEM_read_RSAPublicKey(keyfile, NULL, NULL, NULL);
//rsa_pub == NULL!
```

When I'm reading the private key it works

```
FILE *keyfile = fopen("mykey.pem", "r");
RSA *rsa_pri = PEM_read_RSAPrivateKey(keyfile, NULL, NULL, NULL);
//all good
```

Any ideas?

I've read that openssl generate a X509 key of the RSA public key. But I could not manage to load even a X509 pub key.

Thanks

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You might try `PEM_read_RSA_PUBKEY()` instead of `PEM_read_RSAPublicKey()`.

This is all about formats.

The default public key file format generated by openssl is the PEM format.

`PEM_read_RSA_PUBKEY()` reads the PEM format. `PEM_read_RSAPublicKey()` reads the PKCS#1 format.

So if you want to stick to `PEM_read_RSAPublicKey()` you could generate the public key file using the PKCS#1 format by specifying the `-outform DER` option when generating the public key.

Comment: Have my upvote for writing an explanation far less cryptic than the one mentioned in the OpenSSL docs.

Comment: I generated public key with `-outform DER` but it still gives segmentation fault.

Comment: I want to read public key from memory not from file. I have used `PEM_read_bio_RSA_PUBKEY` but did not work.

Comment: @mustafa.yavuz: As these issues do not seem to be related tio this particular question, please pose your issue  as a new question.

Comment: This answer is incorrect and misleading. Both `PEM_read_RSA_PUBKEY` and `PEM_read_RSAPublicKey` read PEM format, but the former expects a SubjectPublicKeyInfo structure, while the latter expects a RSAPublicKey structure. The former, generated by the openssl command line tool, starts with BEGIN PUBLIC KEY, the latter starts with BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY.

Comment: This Nikolai's comment should be the answer.

Comment: @Nikolai please post that as an answer :)

Answer (score 7):

it seems there are two format of rsa public key, with different encoding.

### A. RSA_PUBKEY

```c
RSA* rsaPubKey = PEM_read_bio_RSA_PUBKEY( bio, NULL, 0, pass ) ;
```

read `PUBKEY` with this format

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
...
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

generated by

```sh
$ openssl rsa -in key.pri -pubout -out key.pub1
```

### B. RSAPublicKey

```c
RSA* rsaPubKey = PEM_read_bio_RSAPublicKey( bio, NULL, 0, pass ) ;
```

read `PublicKey` with this format

```
-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
...
-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
```

generated by

```sh
$ openssl rsa -in key.pri -RSAPublicKey_out -out key.pub2
```

### convert

A to B format

```sh
$ openssl rsa -in key.pub1 -pubin -RSAPublicKey_out -out key.pub2_
```

B to A format

```sh
$ openssl rsa -in key.pub2 -RSAPublicKey_in -pubout -out key.pub1_
```

Answer (score 1):

> The openssl rsa utility saves the public key using the
>   function PEM_write_bio_RSA_PUBKEY and not PEM_write_bio_RSAPubicKey. So,
>   if you want your program to be compatible with its output, then you
>   should use PEM_write_bio_RSA_PUBKEY and PEM_read_bio_RSA_PUBKEY for
>   saving/loading public key files.

http://openssl.6102.n7.nabble.com/RSA-public-private-keys-only-work-when-created-programatically-td12532.html