# openssl initialize RSA public key

Tags: ios, c, encryption, openssl

I have RSA base64 encoded public key that I need to use to verify digital signature. I don't understand how to initialize RSA with public key.

My code looks something like:

```
unsigned char *signature = ""; //signature string
char *original = ""; // my original string
unsigned char sha2HashDigest[SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];
SHA256(original, strlen(original), sha2HashDigest);

 char *key = "base64encodedKey";

 RSA *r = RSA_new();
//SET RSA public key?! how?

int result = RSA_verify(NID_sha256, sha2HashDigest, SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH,
           signature, strlen(signatrue), r);
if (result != 1) // handle error
```

Note: I am doing this in iOS application, but I  think it is irrelevant for the question.

UPDATE: I ended up using EVP as suggested by vond. Public key is PEM formatted file. This is my code:

```
   FILE *fp = fopen([keyFilePath UTF8String], "r");
    if (!fp) return NO;


    EVP_PKEY *pubKey = PEM_read_PUBKEY(fp,NULL,NULL,NULL);
    EVP_MD_CTX     md_ctx;
    EVP_MD_CTX_init(&md_ctx);

    EVP_VerifyInit(&md_ctx, EVP_sha256());
    EVP_VerifyUpdate (&md_ctx, (unsigned char*)[msgData bytes], [msgData length]);
    int  err = EVP_VerifyFinal (&md_ctx, (unsigned char*) sigData, (unsigned int)[sigData length], pubKey);
    EVP_PKEY_free (pubKey);
```

Comment: Is your key in PEM format ? if so, [pem(3)](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/pem.html#) in conjunction with an proper memory BIO is probably what you want.

Comment: it is just base64 string. I can make a pem file out of it, but isn't that unnecessary complication?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You might try the following:

```
const char *pub_key_pem = ...;

BIO *bio = BIO_new_mem_buf((void*)pub_key_pem, strlen(pub_key_pem));
RSA *rsa_pub = PEM_read_bio_RSAPublicKey(bio, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

Note: `PEM_read_bio_RSAPublicKey()` expects PKCS#1 PEM format (with "BEGIN/END RSA PUBLIC KEY" dash lines in the first/last lines); if you have PEM with "BEGIN/END PUBLIC KEY", you should try `PEM_read_bio_RSA_PUBKEY()` instead. See explanation of the difference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7818117/why-i-cant-read-openssl-generated-rsa-pub-key-with-pem-read-rsapublickey) and [here](http://openssl.6102.n7.nabble.com/PEM-read-RSA-PUBKEY-amp-PEM-read-RSAPublicKey-td46350.html).

If you don't have any of these dash lines in your base64 string, you may find it easier to decode the base64 string into a binary buffer, then use one of the `d2i_RSAPublicKey()` or `d2i_RSA_PUBKEY()` to get the `RSA*` public key from it.

Comment: Personally, if possible, I would prefer the high-level EVP interface to the level interface you are trying to use now. See https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/EVP_SignInit.html

Comment: How would I use EVP then? I doesn't have a method for signature validation as far as I can see.

Comment: With EVP, you may need EVP_VerifyInit, EVP_VerifyUpdate and EVP_VerifyFinal, see API at http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/EVP_VerifyInit.html

Comment: Did you try what I suggested in the answer: PEM_read_bio_* or d2i_* ?

Comment: So, what is the outcome with EVP?

Comment: So stupid, I was using the wrong public key all the time, that's why it was failing :D Thanks for the suggested EVP way of doing this.