# How to translate pem public key into openssl RSA* structure

Tags: c, encryption, openssl, cryptography, rsa

Suppose i have to public pem key like this

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQC7vbqajDw4o6gJy8UtmIbkcpnk
O3Kwc4qsEnSZp/TR+fQi62F79RHWmwKOtFmwteURgLbj7D/WGuNLGOfa/2vse3G2
eHnHl5CB8ruRX9fBl/KgwCVr2JaEuUm66bBQeP5XeBotdR4cvX38uPYivCDdPjJ1
QWPdspTBKcxeFbccDwIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

And i want to use openssl

`int RSA_public_decrypt(int flen, const unsigned char *from, unsigned char *to,RSA *rsa, int padding)`. How can i translate the pem key to `RSA *rsa` structure?

FYI: I can't use BIO because i just want to transplant openssl into a bootloader which doesn't have a UNIX filesystem. The only way i can do is translate public key into a C array.

Comment: PEM certificate files contain an base64 encoded X509 certificate. The X509 structure then contains the PUBKEY which is often an RSA key, but there are other certificates that use DSA or elleptic curves... Unfortunately OpenSSL seems to rely on FILE as input for PEM reading data, at least the functions I have found.

Comment: @Robert Thats the problem i have

Answer (score 10):

> I can't use BIO because i just want to transplant openssl into a bootloader which doesn't have a UNIX filesystem

I think you can still use a `BIO`, it just has to be a memory `BIO`, and not a file `BIO`.

If you can't use a memory `BIO` either, then I'm not sure you can use OpenSSL here.

---

> How to translate pem public key into openssl RSA* structure

Use `PEM_read_PUBKEY` or `PEM_read_bio_PUBKEY` (or one of the `*_PUBKEY` routines). They return an `EVP_PKEY`. Then, use `EVP_PKEY_get1_RSA` to convert it to a `RSA`.

Something like:

```
static const char key[] = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n"
    "MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQC7vbqajDw4o6gJy8UtmIbkcpnk\n"
    "O3Kwc4qsEnSZp/TR+fQi62F79RHWmwKOtFmwteURgLbj7D/WGuNLGOfa/2vse3G2\n"
    "eHnHl5CB8ruRX9fBl/KgwCVr2JaEuUm66bBQeP5XeBotdR4cvX38uPYivCDdPjJ1\n"
    "QWPdspTBKcxeFbccDwIDAQAB\n"
    "-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n";

BIO* bio = BIO_new_mem_buf(key, (int)sizeof(key));
ASSERT(bio != NULL);

EVP_PKEY* pkey = PEM_read_bio_PUBKEY(bio, NULL, NULL, NULL);
ASSERT(pkey != NULL);

int type = EVP_PKEY_get_type(pkey);
ASSERT(type == EVP_PKEY_RSA || type == EVP_PKEY_RSA2);

RSA* rsa = EVP_PKEY_get1_RSA(pkey);
ASSERT(rsa != NULL);

...

EVP_PKEY_free(pkey);
RSA_free(rsa);
BIO_free(bio);
```

And here's the helper you need. `EVP_PKEY_get_type` is not part of the library:

```
int EVP_PKEY_get_type(EVP_PKEY *pkey)
{
    ASSERT(pkey);
    if (!pkey)
        return EVP_PKEY_NONE;

    return EVP_PKEY_type(pkey->type);
}
```

---

Related, you can also use the non-PEM version, which is the ASN.1/DER encoding of the key. This will allow you to save some size in the image. Then, you would use `d2i_PUBKEY_bio` to read the key.

Converting from PEM to ASN.1/DER will save about 110 bytes:

```
$ ls -al pubkey.*
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff  162 Jun  5 00:36 pubkey.der
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff  272 Jun  5 00:52 pubkey.pem
```

To convert the PEM encoded public key to ASN.1/DER, follow these steps. First, copy the key to the clipboard. Second, pipe it into `openssl pkey` with a tool like [`pbpaste`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/pbpaste.1.html) on OS X or [`xclip`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xclip) on Linux:

```
$ pbpaste | openssl pkey -pubin -inform PEM -out pubkey.der -outform DER
```

Then, inspect the public key:

```
 $ dumpasn1 pubkey.der 
  0 159: SEQUENCE {
  3  13:   SEQUENCE {
  5   9:     OBJECT IDENTIFIER rsaEncryption (1 2 840 113549 1 1 1)
 16   0:     NULL
       :     }
 18 141:   BIT STRING, encapsulates {
 22 137:     SEQUENCE {
 25 129:       INTEGER
       :         00 BB BD BA 9A 8C 3C 38 A3 A8 09 CB C5 2D 98 86
       :         E4 72 99 E4 3B 72 B0 73 8A AC 12 74 99 A7 F4 D1
       :         F9 F4 22 EB 61 7B F5 11 D6 9B 02 8E B4 59 B0 B5
       :         E5 11 80 B6 E3 EC 3F D6 1A E3 4B 18 E7 DA FF 6B
       :         EC 7B 71 B6 78 79 C7 97 90 81 F2 BB 91 5F D7 C1
       :         97 F2 A0 C0 25 6B D8 96 84 B9 49 BA E9 B0 50 78
       :         FE 57 78 1A 2D 75 1E 1C BD 7D FC B8 F6 22 BC 20
       :         DD 3E 32 75 41 63 DD B2 94 C1 29 CC 5E 15 B7 1C
       :         0F
157   3:       INTEGER 65537
       :       }
       :     }
       :   }
```

Finally, do something like:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    UNUSED(argc), UNUSED(argv);

    static const unsigned char key[] = {
        0x30, 0x81, 0x9f, 0x30, 0x0d, 0x06, 0x09, 0x2a, 0x86, 0x48, 0x86, 0xf7, 0x0d, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01,
        0x05, 0x00, 0x03, 0x81, 0x8d, 0x00, 0x30, 0x81, 0x89, 0x02, 0x81, 0x81, 0x00, 0xbb, 0xbd, 0xba,
        0x9a, 0x8c, 0x3c, 0x38, 0xa3, 0xa8, 0x09, 0xcb, 0xc5, 0x2d, 0x98, 0x86, 0xe4, 0x72, 0x99, 0xe4,
        0x3b, 0x72, 0xb0, 0x73, 0x8a, 0xac, 0x12, 0x74, 0x99, 0xa7, 0xf4, 0xd1, 0xf9, 0xf4, 0x22, 0xeb,
        0x61, 0x7b, 0xf5, 0x11, 0xd6, 0x9b, 0x02, 0x8e, 0xb4, 0x59, 0xb0, 0xb5, 0xe5, 0x11, 0x80, 0xb6,
        0xe3, 0xec, 0x3f, 0xd6, 0x1a, 0xe3, 0x4b, 0x18, 0xe7, 0xda, 0xff, 0x6b, 0xec, 0x7b, 0x71, 0xb6,
        0x78, 0x79, 0xc7, 0x97, 0x90, 0x81, 0xf2, 0xbb, 0x91, 0x5f, 0xd7, 0xc1, 0x97, 0xf2, 0xa0, 0xc0,
        0x25, 0x6b, 0xd8, 0x96, 0x84, 0xb9, 0x49, 0xba, 0xe9, 0xb0, 0x50, 0x78, 0xfe, 0x57, 0x78, 0x1a,
        0x2d, 0x75, 0x1e, 0x1c, 0xbd, 0x7d, 0xfc, 0xb8, 0xf6, 0x22, 0xbc, 0x20, 0xdd, 0x3e, 0x32, 0x75,
        0x41, 0x63, 0xdd, 0xb2, 0x94, 0xc1, 0x29, 0xcc, 0x5e, 0x15, 0xb7, 0x1c, 0x0f, 0x02, 0x03, 0x01,
        0x00, 0x01
    };

    BIO* bio = BIO_new_mem_buf(key, (int)sizeof(key));
    ASSERT(bio != NULL);

    EVP_PKEY* pkey = d2i_PUBKEY_bio(bio, NULL);
    ASSERT(pkey != NULL);

    int type = EVP_PKEY_get_type(pkey);
    ASSERT(type == EVP_PKEY_RSA || type == EVP_PKEY_RSA2);

    RSA* rsa = EVP_PKEY_get1_RSA(pkey);
    ASSERT(rsa != NULL);

    // ...

    EVP_PKEY_free(pkey);
    RSA_free(rsa);
    BIO_free(bio);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: EVP_PKEY_base_id() appears to do exactly what your EVP_PKEY_get_type() function does.  Why they named it that, I don't know.

Comment: @Gammadyne - yeah, I think you are right. Be careful if you use it. It will try to dereference a NULL pointer.

Answer (score 1):

To load the RSA pub key from the pem file

```
int loadKey(string &fileName, RSA ** pubkey)
{

  FILE *fp = fopen(fileName.data(), "r");
  if (fp < 0){
   printf("%s\n","Invalide certificate file name");
   return -1;
 }

 *pubkey = PEM_read_RSA_PUBKEY(fp,pubkey, NULL, NULL);

 if(*pubkey == NULL){
   printf("%s\n","error reading Public key");
   return -1;
 }
```

To verify the signature

```
int verify_signature(vector<uint8_t> &msg, vector<uint8_t> &sig, RSA* pkey)
{
  /* Returned to caller */
  int result = -1;
  vector <uint8_t> pDecrypted(PACKAGE_SIGNATURE_SIZE);


  result = RSA_public_decrypt(PACKAGE_SIGNATURE_SIZE, sig.data(), pDecrypted.data(), pkey, RSA_NO_PADDING);
  if (result == -1)
  {
     printf("RSA_public_decrypt failed with error %s\n", ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL));
    //  goto prog_end;
  }


  /* verify the data */
  result = RSA_verify_PKCS1_PSS(pkey,msg.data() , EVP_sha256(), pDecrypted.data(), -2 /* salt length recovered from signature*/);
  if (result == 1)
  {
     printf("Signature verification successfull!\n");
  }
  else
  {
     printf("RSA_verify_PKCS1_PSS failed with error %s\n", ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL));
  }

  return !!result;

}
```